# Parallel SSH with executorService

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, ssh, executorservice

I have a use case where I have to ssh into 3 different hosts parallely using executorService.
I have M hosts and N jobs for each host, I want to be able to login into M hosts parallely and execute N jobs sequentially (for each host).
I tried SSHJ but seems like it doesn't support parallel SSH.

lately I have been trying around with Parallec, seems like it collects all the tasks and executes parallely based on the concurrency value in config.

Any viable approaches/library ?

Comment: Have you tried JSCH (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a typical work flow / orchestration problem commonly found in managing a cluster of hosts.

With Parallec, you may save the responses / task states to a hash map of  during the `onCompleted()` handler and keep polling the hash map. Whenever you collect at least N jobs finished the current stage, you can fire another parallel task for them to run at the next round.

Say you have 1000 hosts H1...H1000 to run 5 shell scripts S1... S5 sequentially as 5 stages.

You can create a concurrent hash map to store the running status for each host.  Each script/stage will have a [ NOT_RUN | RUNNING | COMPLETED_SUCCESS (COMPLETED_ERROR) ] state. You may also store for each host currently which parallel task is responsible for running it.

You start all the 1,000 hosts to run scripts 1 as the first Parallel Task. Before execution you set each element in the hash map as in <#,RUNNING> state.  Need to execute the task [asynchronously](https://github.com/eBay/parallec-samples/blob/master/sample-apps/src/main/java/io/parallec/sample/app/http/HttpBasicAsyncRunProgressPollingApp.java) so it does not block the current thread. In the response handler `onCompleted()` you parse the results and update the corresponding entry to COMPLETED_X state in the map.

You can keep polling this map with an interval, whenever you find there are at least K tasks (or the last group of tasks left over) in the completed stage, you fire another parallel task with the K hosts that completed the current stage to move to the next stage.

Note that in a parallel task each host may run at different stages.  Some are with Script 1 and some are with Script 4; This is supported with different requests with different hosts: http://www.parallec.io/docs/submit-task/#apis-on-variable-replacement-for-heterogeneous-requests

To sum up, the basic idea is to run as small batch to check which hosts are available to move to the next stage.  As the manager thread only picks up hosts that have finished the current stage for the next round, I do not see need of locking.